# iOS 8 custom keyboard crash when debugging

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

**Issue**

Most times, when I try to debug my custom keyboard extension, I receive the following error and then the keyboard disappears (presumably crashes, so the system removes it from screen and replaces it with the standard keyboard)

```
 plugin com.db.Trype.TrypeKeyboard interrupted
```

(Note: `Trype` is the name of my keyboard.)

**Process**

I am debugging the keyboard the following way:

- I have the keyboard extension as a target.
- I've modified the `TrypeKeyboard` scheme to run my app executable on launch.
- The keyboard has been added in the Simulator's Settings App.

I've tried different version of Xcode-Beta and tried restarting the simulator, computer, etc., all to a **varying degree of temporary success.**

Anyone else run into this error and have a suggestion?

Update:
Here is an accompanying error message. Maybe there is some way to print out more of the UserInfo?

```
 viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3  
 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" 
 UserInfo=0x7fc99c900a50 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Comment: Is it possibly running out of memory for some reason? Are there any other error messages?

Comment: Also, Trype... first thing I thought of: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Trippa_alla_Romana.jpg/1280px-Trippa_alla_Romana.jpg :-)

Comment: @Dan Haha I just pulled the name out of a hat. Didn't know it was a dish. :P If I tweak how I'm debugging it slightly, I can squeeze out a few more errors, but none of them are particularly helpful. It's not running out of memory - my app and keyboard are the bare minimum. ~20MBs

Comment: Cool. Any more error messages will help. And in Romania, they seem to love tripe, so I guess it depends on the market!!! :-P

Comment: Added the extra error message. Thanks for the look!

Comment: I am getting the same issue and nothing I find can resolve it

Comment: Daniel have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

After messing around with it some more, I'm beginning to conclude this is an iOS 8/Xcode bug with the way that extensions are debugged.

Xcode sometimes seems to build project and install *multiple* versions of the extension keyboard into the iOS simulator. It also occasionally kills the extension and reloads it. Very strange behavior. Just sitting and staring at the debugging sidebar shows it get killed (disappear) and then relaunch.

The first is a successful launch.
The second is an *unsuccessful* launch where the extension appears to hang and wait to attach.

[image: Shows both processes attached to the debugger]

[image: Extension waiting to attach]

Comment: interesting. But is this really the answer? I get the same message whenever and only when my keyboard is dismissed (this is at least my current hypothesis), not just randomly...

Comment: @WizardofKneup I don't know. That's why I didn't accept the answer. I know iOS 8 keyboards have a LOT of quirks and bugs *still* and I know they've been changing every Xcode release so it's hard to find one right answer.

Comment: still having this error from time to time while debugging. Anyone with a possible solution or more info ? (running iOS10 Beta8)

Comment: I've got the same problem here. I can't debug my keyboard project. However, I'm able to produce the log file to output. Who knows how to debug keyboard, I'd be appreciated